# Check if something is raisable in any version

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-2.x

I was working on a project where we wanted to validate that a parameter could actually be raised as an exception if necessary. We went with the following:

```
def is_raisable(exception):
    funcs = (isinstance, issubclass)
    return any(f(exception, BaseException) for f in funcs)
```

This handles the following use cases, which meet our needs (for now):

```
is_raisable(KeyError) # the exception type, which can be raised
is_raisable(KeyError("key")) # an exception instance, which can be raised
```

It fails, however, for old-style classes, which are raisable in old versions (2.x). We tried to then solve it this way:

```
IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS = [
    KeyboardInterrupt,
    MemoryError,
    StopIteration,
    SystemError,
    SystemExit,
    GeneratorExit
]
try:
    IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS.append(StopAsyncIteration)
except NameError:
    pass
IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS = tuple(IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS)

def is_raisable(exception, exceptions_to_exclude=IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS):

    funcs_to_try = (isinstance, issubclass)
    can_raise = False

    try:
        can_raise = issubclass(exception, BaseException)
    except TypeError:
        # issubclass doesn't like when the first parameter isn't a type
        pass

    if can_raise or isinstance(exception, BaseException):
        return True

    # Handle old-style classes
    try:
        raise exception
    except TypeError as e:
        # It either couldn't be raised, or was a TypeError that wasn't 
        # detected before this (impossible?)
        return exception is e or isinstance(exception, TypeError)
    except exceptions_to_exclude as e:
        # These are errors that are unlikely to be explicitly tested here,
        # and if they were we would have caught them before, so percolate up
        raise
    except:
        # Must be bare, otherwise no way to reliably catch an instance of an
        # old-style class
        return True
```

This passes all of our tests, but it isn't very pretty, and still feels hacky if we're considering things that we wouldn't expect the user to pass in, but might be thrown in there anyway for some other reason.

```
def test_is_raisable_exception(self):
    """Test that an exception is raisable."""

    self.assertTrue(is_raisable(Exception))

def test_is_raisable_instance(self):
    """Test that an instance of an exception is raisable."""

    self.assertTrue(is_raisable(Exception()))

def test_is_raisable_old_style_class(self):
    """Test that an old style class is raisable."""

    class A: pass

    self.assertTrue(is_raisable(A))

def test_is_raisable_old_style_class_instance(self):
    """Test that an old style class instance is raisable."""

    class A: pass

    self.assertTrue(is_raisable(A()))

def test_is_raisable_excluded_type_background(self):
    """Test that an exception we want to ignore isn't caught."""

    class BadCustomException:
        def __init__(self):
            raise KeyboardInterrupt

    self.assertRaises(KeyboardInterrupt, is_raisable, BadCustomException)

def test_is_raisable_excluded_type_we_want(self):
    """Test that an exception we normally want to ignore can be not
    ignored."""

    class BadCustomException:
        def __init__(self):
            raise KeyboardInterrupt

    self.assertTrue(is_raisable(BadCustomException, exceptions_to_exclude=()))

def test_is_raisable_not_raisable(self):
    """Test that something not raisable isn't considered rasiable."""

    self.assertFalse(is_raisable("test"))
```

Unfortunately we need to continue to support both Python 2.6+ (soon Python 2.7 only, so if you have a solution that doesn't work in 2.6 that's fine but not ideal) and Python 3.x. Ideally I'd like to do that without an explicit test for the version, but if there isn't a way to do it otherwise then that's fine.

Ultimately, my questions are:

1. Is there an easier way to do this and support all listed versions?
2. If not, is there a better or safer way to handle the "special exceptions", e.g. `KeyboardInterrupt`.
3. To be most Pythonic I'd like to ask forgiveness rather than permission, but given that we could get two types of `TypeError` (one because it worked, and one because it didn't) that feels odd as well (but I have to fall back on that anyway for 2.x support).

Comment: "old-style classes [...] are raisable" Not in *any* version, only older ones.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know, but that wasn't clear. I'll edit.

Comment: In any case, I wouldn't worry about it being other than a descendant of `BaseException`; it will need to be one when the code is ported to 3.x regardless.

Comment: Can't you just `try` to `raise` it, and see whether you get a TypeError (not raiseable) or anything else (raiseable)? (Obviously you'd need to special-case `TypeError` there.) It's the same way you test almost anything in Python, even if it feels a bit weird to be testing `raise`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams unfortunately we don't control when (or if) the consumers of the library will upgrade

Comment: And when they do, they won't have to make this particular change in order to make their code work, since they'll have done it long ago.

Comment: @abarnert and I do that, as the fallback. As I mention it gets a little weird with the `TypeError`, and `except type(OldStyleClass)` didn't seem to successfully catch when you pass the type of an old style class, which then means we need the bare except again, which feels unreliable. Right now, by checking if it looks like a `BaseException` we can avoid some of the complexity.

Comment: @Dannnno Look at my answer. I don't think there's anything complicated there, except supporting pre-2.5 `isinstance` safely.

Comment: How far back do you mean by "old versions"? I was trying to write something that works with at least 2.5, if not 2.2 or 2.3, but I see you're using 2.6-only syntax, so maybe I'm solving the wrong problem?

Comment: Like I mentioned, 2.6 is the minimum supported version, but we're (finally) getting off of that if you want to include 2.7-only information

Comment: @abarnert oops, didn't ping you with it the first time. 2.6+ only, and 2.7+ information is interesting as well.

Comment: @Dannnno Ah, it's in the question, I just didn't read carefully enough. Oh well. I think the spirit of my answer—that you don't need all those careful isinstance/issubclass checks—is still right, but I may have spent more effort on irrelevant details than the stuff that matters. I'll check when I get in front of a computer again. Sorry about that.

Comment: By the way, I love that the 2.7 reference docs on exceptions give you all the details about changes between 1.4 and 1.5, but tell you nothing about when all of the subsequent changes happened except for the try/except/finally merger in 2.5. When did raising non-type exceptions get banned? Somewhere between 1.0 and 2.6, that's all you need to know I guess…

Comment: To clarify something in the question: You want to return `True` iff called with something that's raisable _in the Python implementation and version being used_`, not with anything that's raisable in any supported Python, right? (And if you _do_ want the latter, how do you want to handle things like, say, 3.x new-style classes that happen to not have an explicit subclass so they'd be old-style classes in 2.x? And should it be `str` or `bytes` that counts as raisable in 2.6 when tested in 3.x?)

Comment: @abarnert it should only return `True` in the Python version(s) where it is raisable; you correctly pointed out in your answer where my tests were wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you test most things in Python is to `try` then and see whether you get an exception.

That works fine for `raise`. If something isn't raisable, you will get a `TypeError`; otherwise, you will get what you raised (or an instance of what you raised). That will work for 2.6 (or even 2.3) just as well as 3.6. Strings as exceptions in 2.6 will be raisable; types that don't inherit from `BaseException` in 3.6 will be not raisable; etc.—you get the right result for everything. No need to check `BaseException` or handle old-style and new-style classes differently; just let `raise` do what it does.

Of course we do need to special-case `TypeError`, because it'll land in the wrong place. But since we don't care about pre-2.4, there's no need for anything more complicated than an `isinstance` and `issubclass` test; there are no weird objects that can do anything other than return `False` anymore. The one tricky bit (which I initially got wrong; thanks to user2357112 for catching it) is that you have to do the `isinstance` test first, because if the object is a `TypeError` instance, `issubclass` will raise `TypeError`, so we need to short-circuit and return `True` without trying that.

The other issue is handling any special exceptions that we don't want to accidentally capture, like `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemError`. But fortunately, [these all go back to before 2.6](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/exceptions.html). And both [`isinstance`/`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/functions.html#isinstance) and [`except` clauses](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) (as long as you don't care about capturing the exception value, which we don't) can take tuples with syntax that also works in 3.x. Since it's required that we return `True` for those cases, we need to test them before trying to raise them. But they're all `BaseException` subclasses, so we don't have to worry about classic classes or anything like that.

So:

```
def is_raisable(ex, exceptions_to_exclude=IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS):
    try:
        if isinstance(ex, TypeError) or issubclass(ex, TypeError):
            return True
    except TypeError:
        pass
    try:
        if isinstance(ex, exceptions_to_exclude) or issubclass(ex, exceptions_to_exclude):
            return True
    except TypeError:
        pass
    try:
        raise ex
    except exceptions_to_exclude:
        raise
    except TypeError:
        return False
    except:
        return True
```

This doesn't pass your test suite as written, but I think that's because some of your tests are incorrect. I'm assuming you want `is_raisable` to be true for objects that are raisable *in the current Python version*, not objects that are raisable *in any supported version* even if they aren't raisable in the current version. You wouldn't want `is_raisable('spam')` to return `True` in 3.6 and then attempting to `raise 'spam'` would fail, right? So, off the top of my head:

- The `not_raisable` test raises a string--but those are raisable in 2.6.
- The `excluded_type` test raises a class, which Python 2.x *may* handle by instantiating the class, but it isn't required to, and CPython 2.6 has optimizations that will trigger in this case.
- The `old_style` tests raise new-style classes in 3.6, and they're not subclasses of `BaseException`, so they're not raisable.

I'm not sure how to write correct tests without writing separate tests for 2.6, 3.x, and maybe even 2.7, and maybe even for different implementations for the two 2.x versions (although probably you don't have any users on, say, Jython?).

Comment: Unless you get a KeyboardInterrupt at just the wrong time. Then things get weird.

Comment: Getting something like `KeyboardInterrupt` is why I don't like the bare `except`, and where I think some of the extra complexity comes in. Edit: Ninja'd!

Comment: I did not know about the special case type TypeError instances! scary!

Comment: @user2357112 Not _that_ weird. A `KeyboardInterrupt` will get held until after the next instruction if we're in the middle of seeking the handler for a `TypeError`.

Comment: @avigil It's only scary because I don't remember exactly how things that were neither classic classes nor new-style classes (like 2.2 ints) works with `isinstance`, so I want to make sure nobody uses this code without testing on the oldest version they care about… I _think_ it just always returns false for anything else, but I can't test it.

Comment: @abarnert: But we could get a KeyboardInterrupt between entering the `try` and raising `ex`. That would suppress the KeyboardInterrupt and return True, regardless of what `ex` is.

Comment: if you thought that might be a concern you could do the same with `KeyboardInterrupt` as you do with `TypeError` and handle it in a separate block

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, there is a gap there. The real problem is trying to come up with a way to handle `KeyboardInterrupt` and friends without either requiring 2.6+, requiring 2.x only, or writing a separate `except` for each special exception.

Comment: @user2357112 And of course you want `raisable(KeyboardInterrupt)` to return `True`, I think. Or maybe `False`, but you definitely don't want it to exit your program, right?

Comment: @abarnert yeah, we'd want that to be `True`, if for some reason a user decided that was something they need to check

Comment: You mention that explicitly enumerating things like `KeyboardInterrupt` is to work in pre-2.6; since you don't need to support those, is there another, cleaner way?

Comment: @Dannnno After rewriting things, it's not as different from your code as I expected. Although I think it's still simpler and less hacky without needing any `BaseException` tests or treating old-style classes specially. And it handles strings properly.

Comment: `issubclass(ex, TypeError)` will raise an exception immediately when `ex` isn't a class, [including when `ex` is an instance of `TypeError`](https://ideone.com/XsxCaB). `issubclass(ex, exceptions_to_exclude)` has a similar problem.

Comment: @user2357112 That's exactly why those tests are inside a `try`/`except TypeError`. Although thanks for raising the issue with an instance of `TypeError`; the `isinstance` check needs to come first, to short-circuit the `issubclass` test for that one.

Comment: @abarnert looks great, just one thing - the first time you look at `exceptions_to_exclude` should return `True`, because that's something the user passed in and we'd expect to be raisable; I only wanted to ignore them if they come up while raising the exception and they aren't what is passed in

Comment: @Dannnno Oops! Yeah, that seems like the obvious interpretation, and I have no idea how I guessed the opposite. Thanks for pointing it out; I've fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can raise the object, catch the exception and then use the `is` keyword to check that the raised exception is the object or an instance of the object. If anything else was raised, it was a `TypeError` meaning the object was not raisable.

Furthermore, to handle absolutely any raisable object, we can use [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info). This will also catch exceptions such as `KeyboardInterrupt`, but we can then reraise them if the comparison with the argument is inconclusive.

```
import sys

def is_raisable(obj):
    try:
        raise obj
    except:
        exc_type, exc = sys.exc_info()[:2]

        if exc is obj or exc_type is obj:
            return True
        elif exc_type is TypeError:
            return False
        else:
            # We reraise exceptions such as KeyboardInterrupt that originated from outside
            raise

is_raisable(ValueError) # True
is_raisable(KeyboardInterrupt) # True
is_raisable(1) # False
```

Comment: Your text says "If anything else was raised, it was a `ValueError`" Are you sure that's right? (If so, I think your code is wrong—as is mine.)

Comment: Anyway, it does seem like you can safely skip the pre-check for `TypeError` by turning the logic around this way, which is a nice simplification.

Comment: The text above might need rephrasing. But I am not sure what case is not covered here. We either raised our object/class, got a TypeError or got and exception from outside (KeyboardInterrupt, etc.) am I missing something?

Comment: When I `raise 3` in 2.6 or 3.6, I get a `TypeError`, not a `ValueError`. (And I think that's true for any other non-raisable value, and also in 2.7, and that it's guaranteed by the docs.) And your code seems to assume it'll be `TypeError`, not `ValueError`. And my code definitely assumes that.

Comment: Oops! It's my mistake. I really did mean TypeError, this is even what I wrote in my code

Comment: Yeah, I was about 95% sure that your code was right and your text was wrong (because otherwise, how would my code have ever worked last night?), but I didn't want to say so for sure until I could sit down in front of 2.6 and test, and read the docs more carefully.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out. I wrote it fairly late last night so I was totally blind to it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect old-style classes and instances, just make an explicit check for them:

```
import types

if isinstance(thing, (types.ClassType, types.InstanceType)):
    ...
```

You'll probably want to wrap this in some sort of version check so it doesn't fail on Python 3.